# No cue points on Flash CC Pro so how I jump to specific point?

Tags: flash, flv

I try to create a button on Flash CC Pro to jump to a specific point of a FLV Video I've imported.

On Flash CS I know that I could do it adding cue points to the FLV and then, with action script jumping to the cue point. But I see that on Flash Pro CC you cannot add those cue points so how may I set the action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding/Removing Cue Points using UI was deprecated in Flash Pro CC.

You will need to use Actionscript to Add or Remove Cue points and seek to a particular Cue point.

This official doc explains how - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65586-7feb.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7f05

Sample Code:

```
// Requires an FLVPlayback instance called my_FLVPlybk on Stage 
import fl.video.*; 
import fl.video.MetadataEvent; 

//my_FLVPlybk.source = "http://www.helpexamples.com/flash/video/cuepoints.flv" 
var cuePt:Object = new Object(); //create cue point object 
cuePt.time = 2.5; 
cuePt.name = "ASpt1"; 
cuePt.type = "actionscript"; 
my_FLVPlybk.addASCuePoint(cuePt);//add AS cue point 

// add 2nd AS cue point using time and name parameters 
my_FLVPlybk.addASCuePoint(5, "ASpt2"); 

my_FLVPlybk.addEventListener(MetadataEvent.CUE_POINT, cp_listener); 
function cp_listener(eventObject:MetadataEvent):void { 
        trace("Elapsed time in seconds: " + my_FLVPlybk.playheadTime); 
        trace("Cue point name is: " + eventObject.info.name); 
        trace("Cue point type is: " + eventObject.info.type); 
}
```